# How to remove square brackets on either side of string value

Tags: java, javafx

When I choose a row on the table it prints out the selected item in a string as shown. How do I remove the square brackets from either side of the string.

Below is my code to populate TextFields with the data. You can see it populates successfully but with the [].

the table and output

[image: the table and output]

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    String input = newValue.toString();
    String[] str_array = input.split(", ");
    String code = str_array[0]; 
    String name = str_array[1]; 
    String lecturer = str_array[2];
    String year = str_array[3];
    String semester = str_array[4];

    codeInput.setText(code);
    nameInput.setText(name);
    lectureInput.setText(lecturer);
    yearInput.setText(year);
    semesterInput.setText(semester);
    System.out.println(input);
});
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `newValue` is it really necessary to convert it to a String and then extract the values?

Comment: It looks like `newValue` (i.e. the type of the elements in the `TableView`'s backing list) is a `List` here. So why not just do `System.out.println(String.join(", ", newValue));`? (Though, as @Sedrick correctly points out, a `List` is not a good data representation here in the first place.)

Answer (score 3):

You `newValue` should be an `Object`. Let's say it's an object of `SchoolInfo` with variables of `String code`, `String name`, `String lecturer`, `int year`, and `int semester`. Your `Object` should have `Getters` and `Setters`. You should do something like.

**Warning: Some of those other answers may get the job done but are very bad ideas. The way you are trying to handle this data is a bad idea.**

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    SchoolInfo tempSchoolInfo = (SchoolInfo)newValue;

    String code = tempSchoolInfo.getCode(); 
    String name = tempSchoolInfo .getName(); 
    String lecturer = tempSchoolInfo.getLecturer;
    int year = tempSchoolInfo.getYear();
    int semester = tempSchoolInfo.getSemester();

    codeInput.setText(code);
    nameInput.setText(name);
    lectureInput.setText(lecturer);
    yearInput.setText(Integer.toString(year));
    semesterInput.setText(Integer.toString(semester));
    System.out.println(input);
});
```

Comment: `yearInput.setText(Integer.parseInt(year));` - why parse an `int`? Also, why all the temporary variables?

Comment: I followed the OP's code closely. `parseInt` should be `toString()`. Good  catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the first and last character with `input.substr(1, input.length - 1)` or just remove them with `input.replace("[","").replace("]","")` if no other occurrences are possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.stream(str_array).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

this produces desired result without need of 'post processing'