# Add text from Arraylist to TextArea javafx

Tags: listview, javafx, arraylist

I wonder how to do to get various attributes from my objects stored in an ArrayList to my TextArea? 
I have an ListView and depending on which of the lines in the ListView you press, different text should appear in the TextArea. I just can't get it to work.

Here is a bit of my code this far. Animals is another class.

```
    ListView<String> cats = new ListView<>();
    cats.setPrefSize(90, 200);
    cats.getItems().addAll(
            "First cat",
            "Second cat" 
    );

    final ArrayList<Animals> catsdesricption = new ArrayList<Animals>();
    Animals FirstCat = new Animals("First cat", "cats", "is small and fluffy");

    catsdesricption.add(FirstCat);
    TextArea description = new TextArea();
    description.setMaxSize(300, 200);
    description.setWrapText(true);

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Label heading = new Label("Cats");
    heading.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", 20));

    HBox layout = new HBox();

    layout.getChildren().addAll(cats, catsdesricption);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(heading, layout);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 420, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Please provide some code so that someone can provide you a solution

Comment: What you need to do is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174299/how-to-remove-square-brackets-on-either-side-of-string-value/49175234#49175234). Listen to the selection model and update textfields accordingly.

Comment: How is `layout.getChildren().addAll(cats, catsdesricption);` compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look at your code, I noticed a ton of problems. To answer your original question. You need a listener on the `SelectionModel's` `ItemProperty` to updated the `TextArea`.

```
    cats.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldAnimal, newAnimal) -> {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("Name: ").append(newAnimal.getName()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        stringBuilder.append("Type: ").append(newAnimal.getType()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        stringBuilder.append("About: ").append(newAnimal.getAbout()).append(System.lineSeparator());        

        description.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    });
```

**First problem:**

```
ListView<String> cats = new ListView<>();
cats.setPrefSize(90, 200);
cats.getItems().addAll(
        "First cat",
        "Second cat" 
);
```

It appears you want the `ListView` to hold `Animal` objects, but you are using `String` objects.

**The Fix**

```
ListView<Animal> cats = new ListView<>();
cats.getItems().add(new Animal("First cat", "cats", "is small and fluffy"));
cats.getItems().add(new Animal("Second cat", "cats", "is big and fluffy"));
```

**Second Problem:** 
Now that the `ListView` is handling `Animal` objects, we need to use the `ListView's` `CellFActory` to tell the `ListView` what text to display. In this case, the name will be displayed.

```
    cats.setCellFactory((ListView<Animal> param) -> {
        ListCell<Animal> cell = new ListCell<Animal>() {                
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Animal item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item.getName());
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };

        return cell;
    });
```

Now that these two things are done, the original question code can be added. The code above that changes the `TextArea's` text depending on which item is selected in the `ListView`.

**Full Code:**

**Main**

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     * JavaFX App
     */
    public class App extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            ListView<Animal> cats = new ListView<>();
            cats.getItems().add(new Animal("First cat", "cats", "is small and fluffy"));
            cats.getItems().add(new Animal("Second cat", "cats", "is big and fluffy"));

            cats.setCellFactory((ListView<Animal> param) -> {
                ListCell<Animal> cell = new ListCell<Animal>() {                
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Animal item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item.getName());
                        } else {
                            setText("");
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }); 
            cats.setPrefSize(90, 200);           

            TextArea description = new TextArea();
            description.setMaxSize(300, 200);
            description.setWrapText(true);

            cats.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldAnimal, newAnimal) -> {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append("Name: ").append(newAnimal.getName()).append(System.lineSeparator());
                stringBuilder.append("Type: ").append(newAnimal.getType()).append(System.lineSeparator());
                stringBuilder.append("About: ").append(newAnimal.getAbout()).append(System.lineSeparator());        

                description.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            });

            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            Label heading = new Label("Cats");
            heading.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", 20));

            HBox layout = new HBox(cats, description);

            vbox.getChildren().addAll(heading, layout);

            Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 420, 250);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch();
        }    
    }
```

**My Animal Class:** (You did not post yours)

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String about;

    public Animal(String name, String type, String about) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Animals{name=").append(name);
        sb.append(", type=").append(type);
        sb.append(", about=").append(about);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I do if I want to add different types of fonts and fontsizes to the different cat's name, type and description when printing it out in the TextArea?

Comment: Research the problem. If you can't find a solution, ask a new question.