# How to get selected item from ListView

Tags: mysql, javafx

I've been messing around with MySQL database using JavaFX. I have a database of dogs containing over 9 thousand entries. I got a initialize method that loads all the data from the database into one ListView.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try (Connection spojeni = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/psi", "root", "");
         PreparedStatement dotaz = spojeni.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM psi");
         ResultSet vysledky = dotaz.executeQuery();) {

        while (vysledky.next()) {
            String nazev = vysledky.getString("celejmeno");
            list.getItems().add(nazev);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Chyba při komunikaci s databází " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I also got ID's of the dogs in the database (ID's of the father and mother of the dog).
Is there any way to do something like: If I click the item in the ListView, it will send the name of the selected dog into a Label and also, read the ID of the dog's father and mother and looks it up in the database

-> I click on a certain entry, let's say Dog#1

-> It fills the name of the dog into a Label ("jmeno")

-> the program searches in the database for the name of the mother and father of the dog using their ID's

-> it sends the name of the father into Label ("otec") and mother's name into Label ("matka")

Do I have to use some sort of EventHandler/method to pull out the name/Id of the selected dog? If yes, which one?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#selectionModelProperty

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976085/add-text-from-arraylist-to-textarea-javafx/58978474#58978474 helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this approach:
Create list of objects:

```
private ObservableList<Dog> dogList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Create ListView in xml or in controller using a custom object:

```
@FXML
private ListView<Dog> dogListView;
```

In your initialize method fetch items from database and set Cell Factory for list to show only dog names

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        dogList.setAll(fetchDogList()); //create method to return list of dogs from database
        dogListView.setItems(dogList); //bind observable list with ListView
        dogListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Dog> call(ListView<Dog> association) {
                return new ListCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Dog association, boolean bool) {
                        super.updateItem(association, bool);
                        if (association != null) setText(association.getName());
                        else setText(null);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        //create on select event:
        dogListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //avoid exception when nothing is selected as pointed out by @kleopatra
            if (newValue != null) { 
                //set text to your label
                myLabel.setText(newValue.getName());
                getParentsByDogId(newValue.getId());
            }
        });
```

Crete method to get dog parents by dog ID:

```
getParentsByDogId(int dogId) {
    //fetch data from DB based on dogId, set label names based on DB result
}
```

Create Dog class with dog info fileds like this:

```
public class Dog {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //add other fields/properties
    //add getter and setter
}
```